# How to get JSON from REACT JS to implement in NODE js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying implement REST API using REACT AND NODE. How to get JSON from front end(REACT JS)drag and drop images in template  ex."https://www.canva.com/templates/" to store JSON in Mongodb using NODE JS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch api to call a particular route and send data along with it to nodejs backend.
You just need to do simply like this:

```
async function sendData(){
  let res = await fetch(url, {
       method: 'POST',
       mode: 'CORS',
       body: {}, //the json object you want to send
       headers: {}, //if required
     }
  )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Harshit,

Thanks for the reply. This is something how API works from front end - back end but query was to implement from "https://www.canva.com/templates/" .Can you please the link to get JSON from front end?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how to send JSON to node.js I'm assuming you do not yet have an API that your front end can use.

To send data to the back end you need to create an API that accepts data. 
You can do this quickly and easily using [express.js](https://expressjs.com).

Once the server is running and it has an endpoint to send data to, you can create a request (e.g. when sending data it should be a POST request).
This can be done in many different ways, although I would suggest trying [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example to get the Json value and update it.

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'+ this.props.id + '/')
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                // do some action
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: Hello Sugumar,

Thanks from your reply. My REST api using REACT and NODE is working.My issue is from the above link "https://www.canva.com/templates/" is to implement the logic to get json.
1. Select template from left menu like poster,logo,card then -> use this template,will lead to the next tab.
2. drag background, text, photo from the left menu tool and drop into the canvas, that is auto saving.

Comment: Hello Sugumar,

Thanks from your reply. My REST api using REACT and NODE is working.My issue is from the above link "https://www.canva.com/templates/" is to implement the logic to get json.
1. Select template from left menu like poster,logo,card then -> use this template,will lead to the next tab.
2. drag background, text, photo from the left menu tool and drop into the canvas, that is auto saving.
3. Then this canvas is saved as JSON to send to node js to save in Mongodb.
4. again that can be reopened to edit and save etc...

Thanks,